# Is there a drug being developed for heart palpitations without arrhythmia?

Tags: cardiology, cardiovascular-disease

Is there a drug being developed for palpitations without arrhythmia?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82471/discussion-on-question-by-esonat-is-there-a-drug-being-developed-for-heart-palpi).

Comment: I would recommend you read the policies on how the site works, especially including our "Be Nice" policy. Also, this is not a forum where you can get consults from cardiologists or other specialists, which you would know if you read the help and about sections. Berating people attempting to help doesn't exactly encourage others to help. I understand you are anxious and worried, but your best recourse is to visit a qualified cardiologist that can physically examine you and administer tests.

Comment: OP From Chat: *How can you know the truth while you are not even an expert? Even an expert can't know for sure if a drug is being developed.* Therefore, the question can't be answered if no one can know whether a drug is being developed, and hence I'm voting to close it as primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Narusan It is knowledge-based not opinion-based.I didn't say no one can know whether a drug is being developed.If there is someone who has this knowledge he should go ahead and post an answer.Anyone can know the answer.It doesn't have to be an expert.And there is no logic and benefit in trying to close this question while thinking that it is opinion based which it is not where millions of palpitations sufferers like me are waiting for an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A definitive answer is unlikely because drug companies don't normally make it publicly known what drugs they're developing.

There are a number of [antiarrhythmic drugs](https://www.merckmanuals.com/professional/cardiovascular-disorders/arrhythmias-and-conduction-disorders/drugs-for-arrhythmias) already available that could possibly treat palpitations, and there are also [ablation procedures](https://www.mayoclinic.org/tests-procedures/cardiac-ablation/about/pac-20384993). Treatments exist now for arrhythmias.